Tukey post-hoc test not giving exact p-value
I am running a model in R to look at differences between subareas and age classes over many years.
 (snippet of what the data looks like)
This is my model:  m1<-glmmTMB(Quantity ~ Subarea+ AgeClass, family=truncated_nbinom2(link = "log"), data=df1_m1_52)
After the results came back significant,
glmmTMB:::Anova.glmmTMB(m1, type = c("II", "III", 2, 3), test.statistic = c("Chisq", "F"),
+                         component = "cond", vcov. = vcov(m1))
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Quantity
          Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Subarea  65.298 10  3.555e-10 ***
AgeClass 19.858  2  4.873e-05 ***
--- 

I ran a Tukey's post-hoc test and got the following results:
pairs(emmeans(m1, ~AgeClass, component="cond"),type="response", 
+       bias.adjust=F, adj="Tukey", infer=(TRUE))
contrast ratio    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL null z.ratio p.value
A / SA   4.214 1.370 Inf     1.967     9.028    1   4.425  <.0001
A / Y    1.393 0.325 Inf     0.807     2.405    1   1.423  0.3291
SA / Y   0.331 0.119 Inf     0.142     0.767    1  -3.083  0.0058

Results are averaged over the levels of: Subarea 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
Tests are performed on the log scale 

Now my issue is that I need the exact p-value for these results. How do I tell R to give them to me rather than "<0.0001"?

Can you please post your data snippet in a text form rather than as an image/screenshot?

Just wrap the results from pairs() into as.data.frame(), and extract the p.value column: as.data.frame(pairs(...))$p.value.

No, you do not need an exact P value in that range.

Yes, I do. The journal I am looking to publish in asks for the exact values.

@YvonneS OK, well you can get it using data.frame(). The journal or the reviewer? But unless you are vulnerable, you should comment that this is unnecessary, and it's about as meaningless as a traffic cop measuring your speed to 4 decimal places. In any case, make sure you are clear that the P values you report are Tukey-adjusted.

This is likely just a function of how it prints outputs. You should be able to do something like this
library(glmmTMB)

data(Owls)


m1 = glmmTMB(SiblingNegotiation ~ FoodTreatment + Nest + BroodSize, family = truncated_nbinom2(link = 'log'), zi = ~FoodTreatment, data = Owls)
#> dropping columns from rank-deficient conditional model: BroodSize

get_pvals = pairs(emmeans::emmeans(m1, ~FoodTreatment, component = 'cond'), type = 'response', bias.adjust = FALSE, adj = 'Tukey', infer = TRUE) 
  
get_pvals |> 
  broom::tidy()
#> # A tibble: 1 × 9
#>   term         contrast null.value ratio std.error    df  null statistic p.value
#>   <chr>        <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 FoodTreatme… Deprive…          0  1.27     0.102   Inf     1      2.97 0.00302

summary(get_pvals)$p.value
#> [1] 0.003019641

Created on 2024-08-30 with reprex v2.1.1
